# Seed data for grails application

Tags: grails, seed

What is the best way to load seed (initial or test) data into grails application. I'm considering 3 options

1. Putting everything in *BootStrap.groovy files. This is tedious if the domain classes and test data are many.
2. Write custom functionality to load it through xml. May not be too difficult with the excellent xml support by groovy, but lot of switch statements for different domain classes.
3. Use Liquibase LoadData api. I see you can load the data fairly easy from csv files.

Choice 3 seems the easiest. But, I'm not familiar with Liquibase. Is it good in this scenario, or only used for migration, db changes etc. If anyone could provide a better sol, or point to an example with Liquibase, it would be great help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another answer would be to leverage grails run-script. This would allow you to move what you might put in bootstrap and keep it where you want on your file system (possibly outside of the codebase). Similarly, you could install the console plugin and load code through that on a running application.

Depending on your data needs, check out the great build-test-data plugin as well.

Comment: Grails RunScript: However what if we want to do this in QA or UAT environment, this method requires us to have the "grails context" on the server, no? grails run-script requires grails as well as the project (source code) installed in the server, right? will grails run-script work outside the grails development context?

Comment: In that case, you might want to look into the console or remote control plugins. With the console plugin, you can run scripts or arbitrary groovy code on a running instance with full access to. Keep in mind this should be disabled or heavily guarded on a production deployment.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the Fixtures plugin to load test/initial data, it works for me.

http://www.grails.org/plugin/fixtures

Comment: thanks for the pointer.. I meanwhile decided to do it my own from xml.. I didn't explore much, but didn't see much example of fixtures usage.. Is it easy to use with one-many, many-many etc scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

look at http://www.dbunit.org/ and http://www.grails.org/DBUnit+Plugin

Comment: link is broken 2021

Comment: yes. maybe it moved. http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins-releases/org/dbunit/dbunit/2.5.4/ - it shut down in 2017 - https://github.com/codehaus/dbunit

Answer (score 0):

look into SeedMe plugin: 
https://github.com/bertramdev/seed-me

```
seed = {
    author(meta:[key:'name'], name: 'David', description: 'Author Bio Here')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way I have generated seed data is using a service. I created a class, lets call it SeederService. I can inject this service in the Bootstrap.groovy and call whatever method I would want.

The beauty of SeederService is that you can also use the same service in your unit-tests. Simply inject the service class in your unit test and generate your seed data.