# Initial data for grails application

Tags: grails, groovy, ggts

I am developing a small grails application from a book and one of the steps it needs is to feed the database with initial data. When I do so using the `GroovyConsole`, the script executes but doesnt persist the data.

`DataSource.groovy` environment settings are as follows

```
development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:h2:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
        }
    }
```

When I run the script in console, `result` returns `NULL`. I have been using GGTS for the application but I have no idea how to persist initial data from GGTS so I ran the `grails console` command from the command prompt for this. Is this the right way? Is there a way to do it directly from GGTS?

PS: I have seen this question [Seed data for grails application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705412/seed-data-for-grails-application) but it seems to be too advanced for where I am now and what I need.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

prepare a SQL file with the `insert`-statements you need and run it in the `BootStrap.groovy`:

```
class BootStrap {

  def dataSource 

  def init = { servletContext ->
    Sql sql = new Sql( dataSource )
    new File( pathToSql ).eachLine{ sql.executeInsert it }
    sql.commit()
    sql.close()
  }
}
```

is simple enough, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you quite different approach. Create a service called e.g. **BootstrapInitialDataService** with one method called **initData()**. It's a good practice to extract an interface from that class (let's call it **InitialDataService**) so you can easily define different component bean for your development and production environments.
In this initData() method you can simply create all your domain objects, but remember to check first if they already exist in the database. When you do this, inject this service in Bootstrap.groovy and run initData() in the bootstrap's init closure:

```
class Bootstrap {

def initialDataService

def init = {

    initialDataService.initData()
}
```

In the resources.groovy file you can explicitly define your initialDataService bean:

```
beans = {
    //.... other beans definition goes here

    initialDataService(your.package.BootstrapInitialDataService)
}
```

Thanks that when you decide to change your init data bootstrap logic you would simply define a new bean and replace the definition in the resources.groovy - the rest stays the same. You can even use an environment switch to inject different beans in different environments - that's very powerful advantage.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add code in BootStrap.groovy under
`{project}/grails-app/init/{project}/BootStrap.groovy`

For example:

```
class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->
        // create a driver a save it in db
        def user = new User(name: "juan")
        driver.save()
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```